# Elasticsearch plugin add/remove using Azure RM template

Tags: azure, templates, elasticsearch, plugins, azure-resource-manager

I am using [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/elastic/elasticsearchelasticsearch/) template to setup elasticsearch and kibana on Azure. How do you add/remove plugins to a cluster which is deployed using the ARM template above ? e.g. The ARM template, by default deploys the Marvel plugin, even though it will stop working after a month unless a license is applied, I want to remove it and add another plugin.

Comment: What ARM template are you using? Can you update that in your question?

Comment: Updated with the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Marvel has a Basic license](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/license-management.html) which provides access to the key monitoring features. This license is free for commercial use, you just need to register your details to be granted a license.

The Azure ARM template is an easy way to get an Elasticsearch cluster deployed and running in Azure and once deployed, you would manage it in the same way as you would manage a cluster on your own hardware or any other cloud provider. To install and uninstall plugins, you'll need to run the plugin install script on each node within the cluster.

To do this, you'll first need to ssh into each node. You can gain external access to each Elasticsearch node through the public IP address of a machine in the same network as the cluster; the Kibana IP or the jumpbox IP (if you installed one) can be used

```
ssh <Kibana IP address>
```

You'll need an ssh key set up and will use either the password or ssh key that you configured on the first step (Basic settings) to gain access. Once you're logged into this machine, you can then ssh into each of the nodes in the cluster using the internal IP address of each machine. You can find each internal IP address by looking at the attached devices on the virtual network in the Azure portal. For example, once ssh'ed into the Kibana node, to gain access to a master node on 10.0.0.5 would be

```
ssh 10.0.0.5
```

Again, use the password or ssh key that you configured on the first step to gain access.

Once you have access to a node, you can install plugins through the plugin install script. For example, to install the mapper-attachments plugin on an Elasticsearch 2.4.0 node would be

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install mapper-attachments
```

You then need to start/restart the node.

[Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) is installed onto each VM as part of the deployment, to automatically restart the elasticsearch process if it unexpectedly stops. If you want to stop the service to install plugins, use monit to stop the process

```
sudo monit -g elasticsearch stop
```

If you see the error

> monit: Cannot connect to the monit daemon. Did you start it with http support?

Then restart the monit service using

```
sudo service monit restart
```

and run the command again to stop the elasticsearch group

```
sudo monit -g elasticsearch stop
```

Once you have made your changes, you can start elasticsearch service again using

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
sudo monit start all
```

This will also start monit again to monitor the elasticsearch service.

To ensure that you install the plugin on all nodes in the cluster, it would be a good idea to automate this process with something like [Puppet](https://puppet.com/).

[The template is open source under the MIT license](https://github.com/elastic/azure-marketplace) so an alternative route would be to clone/fork this repository, make changes to the [`elasticsearch-ubuntu-install.sh`](https://github.com/elastic/azure-marketplace/blob/master/src/scripts/elasticsearch-ubuntu-install.sh) script and then deploy this modified deployment template.

In case you missed it, there's also [a blog post highlighting some of the features available in the ARM template.](https://www.elastic.co/blog/spinning-up-a-cluster-with-elastics-azure-marketplace-template)

Comment: Thanks ! Great answer :)

Comment: @dp - just a note: if you're forking the repo, make changes to the latest released version of the template i.e. the latest tagged commit. The `master` branch may have changes in it that are not yet released and are still in progress, so best to work off last "good" release :)